# Ansible triggering a task for **specific host** from a role

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, devops

I want to run a specific task in a playbook to a single host. Is there any better way to do that?

custom playbook

```
---
- hosts: swarm_manager
  roles:
  - custom_role
```

roles/custom_role/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: checking for ip
  shell: docker service ps service | grep Running | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
  register: ip

- name: killing the container
  **hosts: "{{ip.stdout}}"**
  shell: docker kill $(docker service ps | grep service | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit doing the following:

```
---
- name: checking for ip
  shell: docker service ps service | grep Running | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
  register: ip

- name: killing the container
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ip.stdout}}"
  shell: docker kill $(docker service ps | grep service | awk '{print $1}')
```

I have tested it this way:

```
---
- hosts: linux
  roles:
  - test_role
```

And then:

```
- name: Set Fact
  set_fact:
    ip: 10.100.10.10

- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars[groups['linux'][0]]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']}}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: "{{ip}}"
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have one more concern. 
since the ip is dynamically generated and it is not in the host file, ansible will throw an error saying that couldn't ssh and permission denied. I know we can pass `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` in vars. But is there any way to set a default key for ansible ssh connections?

Comment: Hi! You can use it in your ansible.cfg and even work with your .ssh/config file